# It is possible to use regex in Javascript onclick event (HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, jquery-events

My question is quite simple but I cannot find the truth.
It is possible to use regex in Javascript `onclick` event (HTML)? 
For example is it possible to show div with different id but a same tag using regex :

> div s:

```
<div class='zone' id='{{site.City}}'>
<div class='zone' id='{{site.City}}{{immo.CodeImmo}}'>
<div class='zone' id='{{site.City}}{{sth else}}'>
```

> javascript regex :

```
onclick='$("#/^{{site.City}}./").show();'
```

I am worried about the regex syntax in the Javascript `onclick` event.
Is it possible? and how is it possible to do it?
This question is for my personal knowledge.

**EDIT :**
ok I know now I can use:

```
onclick=`$('div[id*="{{site.City}}"]').show();`
```

but how can I do if `{{site.City}}` is a chain variable?
What is the syntax for a loop in `onclick` even with a django dictionary variable?
It's not the topic. It is still for my knowledge.

Comment: Why not just attach the event handlers using the class name?

Comment: Take a [**`jQuery selector`**](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), ie `$('.zone')`.

Comment: You don't seem to need a regex, you can use the attribute starts with selector.

Comment: well I dont use selector with class because for the same class I wanted different event That's why I use id. I did what I wanted using class but just wanted to know how I can possibly works with id and regex

Comment: @Stages: Just use another class then. Or `data`

Comment: @Jan I know this works, that's what I did in my programm. I just wanted to know if regex exist in Javascript in an onclick event and the way to do it. just for knowledge :) thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is impossible to use RegEx in jQuery selectors. You can, however, use css selectors for these IDs. This will match all `div`s with an id that contains "`{{site.City}}`".

```
div[id*="{{site.City}}"]
```

That would make your onClick attribute look like this (note the different quotation marks):

```
onclick=`$('div[id*="{{site.City}}"]').show();`
```

If you would like the `id`s to start with `{{site.City}}`, use:

```
div[id^="{{site.City}}"]
```

More details on selectors can be found on the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

Comment: yes its a good idea but there are one matter here : you should know that site.City is for a list/dictionnary with several cities so how can I use this kind of selectors to select only (for example) 2 City on 5? and btw the City Immo and sth else. I know this is kind of wierd.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a class selector:

```
<div class='zone site-city' id='{{site.City}}'>
<div class='zone site-city' id='{{site.City}}{{immo.CodeImmo}}'>
<div class='zone site-city' id='{{site.City}}{{sth else}}'>

<a onclick='$(".site-city").show();'>Some anchor</a>
```

**EDIT:** AFAIK it's not possible to use regular expressions as selectors with jQuery. The closest approach is to use "starts-with" (`[attr^=start]`) and "ends-with" (`[attr$=end]`) selectors, which in your case would be:

```
onclick='$("[id^='{{site.City}}']").show();'
```

**EDIT 2:** If you **really** need to match elements based on complex patterns, then you might need to do it in two steps:

```
$("div.zone").filter(function () {
    return /your regex here/.test($(this).attr('id'));
}).show();
```

Comment: thx I know this works but it does not repond to my question. I am worried about how doing this using only id and maybe regex to do things work.

Comment: ok thx it's the same idea of @Mark Langer. So how can I do know if site.City is a caracter chain variable? for example : NewYork, Chicago, LosAngeles, Denver... and I dont want to show only the things for Chicago ans NewYork? Do you thing it is possible using for in the onclick event?

Comment: It is, but only if you prefix your `id` attributes like: `id='city-{{site.City}}'` then you can `onclick='$("[id^='city-']").show();'`.

Comment: However, I strongly recommend you use classes since they were invented to solve problems like yours.

Comment: I agree it's way more simple. So it is not possible to use any Different Kinds of Loops (for, while) in onclick event?

Comment: You can actually put any JavaScript code inside an `onclick` attribute, but I don't think I get what you really want to achieve.

Comment: well it's a bit complicated. I have a database with a table for Cities and another for buildings linked to the appropriate City (each building is unique). For each building some information as to be shown on the web interface. The user can hide or show Cities (wich regroup buildings and info) and hide or show buildings (which contain info). There are buttons show all, hide all and a select for each City/building with the onclickj event .show(). This works pretty easily with class and id (class for show all and hide all; id for show one).

Comment: The matter is there is another table with saving config where the user can save which Cities he wanted for the show all button (but class and id are already used). If you are interested to discuss this or if you want more explanation or screenshots maybe we should moove to chat or what? If you have some time to loose

Comment: I'm actually going to sleep now. But I still insist that this can be done with CSS classes.